# What is the determinant of a weighted orthogonal projection (based on the weighted pseudo-inverse)?

Tags: matrices, determinant, pseudoinverse

What is the determinant of a weighted orthogonal projection (based on the weighted pseudo-inverse)? E.g. I have

$$ J = A \left( A^\intercal W A \right)^{-1} A^\intercal W $$

and would like to know $\det (J)$. Note that $A$ is not square while $W$, $J$, and $A^\intercal W A$ are square.

Comment: @Surb Sorry - I got that one wrong => J is square, I had omitted the $A$ at the beginning! Please re-check!

Comment: Well then, the properties of the determinant listed in @Chris answer should give you what you want, namely $\det(J)=1$ if I'm not wrong.

Comment: @Surb But $A$ is not square, which conflicts with Chris' derivation.

Comment: @JennyReininger right.

Comment: If $A$ isn't square, it must be a tall matrix and hence $\det(J)=0$.

Comment: Is $W$ diagonal?

Comment: If it simplifies things, yes. It could also just be positive definite.

Comment: Hint: Examine $J(I-J)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kernel of any projection onto a proper subspace is nontrivial. If $A$ is not square, then its columns don’t span the entire ambient space, therefore $J$ is rank-deficient and $\det(J)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Given that 
$$
\det A^{-1} = \det(A)^{-1}
$$
and 
$$ 
\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)
$$ 
I would say 
$$ 
\det((A^T W A)^{-1} A^T W) = \frac{1}{\det A}
$$

Comment: Why assume that $A$ is square?

Comment: Thank you for helping me debug the question! Now, I just need to find the answer...